# Get ISO-8601(SCORM 2004) Duration Format in Seconds using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, iso8601

I have a sql column with values like

```
PT2M52.37S
PT21.79S
PT53M29.68S
P
PT9S
```

Is it possible with some **MySQL** Functions to convert the above format to seconds?

I have searched everything but didn't find something in exactly the same format as above.
Any date mysql function I tried isn't working.

More information regarding this format: http://www.ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/ISOTimeForSCORM.htm

PHP Function (it always will be P, the first char)

```
function scorm_format_duration($duration) {
    // Fetch date/time strings.
    $stryears = get_string('years');
    $strmonths = get_string('nummonths');
    $strdays = get_string('days');
    $strhours = get_string('hours');
    $strminutes = get_string('minutes');
    $strseconds = get_string('seconds');

    if ($duration[0] == 'P') {
        // If timestamp starts with 'P' - it's a SCORM 2004 format
        // this regexp discards empty sections, takes Month/Minute ambiguity into consideration,
        // and outputs filled sections, discarding leading zeroes and any format literals
        // also saves the only zero before seconds decimals (if there are any) and discards decimals if they are zero.
        $pattern = array( '#([A-Z])0+Y#', '#([A-Z])0+M#', '#([A-Z])0+D#', '#P(|\d+Y)0*(\d+)M#',
                            '#0*(\d+)Y#', '#0*(\d+)D#', '#P#', '#([A-Z])0+H#', '#([A-Z])[0.]+S#',
                            '#\.0+S#', '#T(|\d+H)0*(\d+)M#', '#0*(\d+)H#', '#0+\.(\d+)S#',
                            '#0*([\d.]+)S#', '#T#' );
        $replace = array( '$1', '$1', '$1', '$1$2 '.$strmonths.' ', '$1 '.$stryears.' ', '$1 '.$strdays.' ',
                            '', '$1', '$1', 'S', '$1$2 '.$strminutes.' ', '$1 '.$strhours.' ',
                            '0.$1 '.$strseconds, '$1 '.$strseconds, '');
    } else {
        // Else we have SCORM 1.2 format there
        // first convert the timestamp to some SCORM 2004-like format for conveniency.
        $duration = preg_replace('#^(\d+):(\d+):([\d.]+)$#', 'T$1H$2M$3S', $duration);
        // Then convert in the same way as SCORM 2004.
        $pattern = array( '#T0+H#', '#([A-Z])0+M#', '#([A-Z])[0.]+S#', '#\.0+S#', '#0*(\d+)H#',
                            '#0*(\d+)M#', '#0+\.(\d+)S#', '#0*([\d.]+)S#', '#T#' );
        $replace = array( 'T', '$1', '$1', 'S', '$1 '.$strhours.' ', '$1 '.$strminutes.' ',
                            '0.$1 '.$strseconds, '$1 '.$strseconds, '' );
    }

    $result = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $duration);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: the above format is an ISO one. I'm asking if there is any ready to use function. If it is manual, i don't even know what kind of different possibilities we have. In the frist example though is 2 minutes, 52 seconds and 37 miliseconds.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes is exactly that.

Comment: ISO-8601 refers to a variety of formats.  These look like [durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).  IMX, most of the time people talk about ISO-8601 and databases, they're talking about ISO dates or datetimes.  You might be able to use `STR_TO_DATE()`, but it probably won't be pretty with such a varying format..

Comment: Someone seems to have gotten it to work with `STR_TO_DATE()` [here](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,513057,513508#msg-513508) their complete command was `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('PT13M22S', 'PT%iM%sS');` but it sadly and frustratingly doesn't work for me no idea why.

Answer (score 4):

To make the `STR_TO_DATE` works, you need to add `%f` for the Microseconds.

```
SELECT duration,
CASE
    WHEN duration LIKE 'P%DT%H%M%.%S' THEN STR_TO_DATE(duration, 'P%dDT%HH%iM%s.%fS')
    WHEN duration LIKE 'P%DT%H%M%S' THEN STR_TO_DATE(duration, 'P%dDT%HH%iM%sS')
    WHEN duration LIKE 'PT%H%M%.%S' THEN STR_TO_DATE(duration, 'PT%HH%iM%s.%fS')
    WHEN duration LIKE 'PT%H%M%S' THEN STR_TO_DATE(duration, 'PT%HH%iM%sS')
    WHEN duration LIKE 'PT%M%.%S' THEN STR_TO_DATE(duration, 'PT%iM%s.%fS')
    WHEN duration LIKE 'PT%M%S' THEN STR_TO_DATE(duration, 'PT%iM%sS')
    WHEN duration LIKE 'PT%.%S' THEN STR_TO_DATE(duration, 'PT%s.%fS')
    WHEN duration LIKE 'PT%S' THEN STR_TO_DATE(duration, 'PT%sS')
END as session
FROM db
```

`PT27M59.08S => 00:27:59.080000`

`PT2H27M37.11S => 02:27:37.110000`

`P4DT19H46M18.22S => 115:46:18.220000`

Answer (score 1):

I've been created 2 functions to convert the result of **cmi.session_time** and **cmi.total_time** form ISO8601 to seconds:

```
CREATE FUNCTION 'ISO8601_duration_delete_miliseconds'('isoDuration' VARCHAR(512)) RETURNS varchar(512) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
  DECLARE strIndex INT;
  DECLARE strRes varchar(512);

  SET strIndex = INSTR(isoDuration, '.');
  if (strIndex > 0) then
    set strRes = substring(isoDuration, 1, strIndex-1);
    set strRes = concat(strRes, 'S');
  else
    set strRes = isoDuration;
  end if;

  RETURN strRes;
END
```

And the final function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `iso8601duration_to_seconds`(`isoDuration` VARCHAR(512)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
  DECLARE strIndex INT;
  DECLARE strRes varchar(512);
  DECLARE intRes INT;

  set strRes =  ISO8601_duration_delete_miliseconds(isoDuration);

  if (INSTR(isoDuration, 'H') > 0) then
    set intRes = time_to_sec(str_to_date(strRes, 'PT%HH%iM%sS'));
  elseif (INSTR(isoDuration, 'M') > 0) then
    set intRes = time_to_sec(str_to_date(strRes, 'PT%iM%sS'));
  else
    set intRes = time_to_sec(str_to_date(strRes, 'PT%sS'));
  end if;

  RETURN intRes;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard function for doing this.  Using `str_to_date()` is a possibility, but it will fail on missing time components.  If you only have minute and second components, you can do this painfully with string operations.

```
select ((case when p like '%M%S'
              then substring_index(substring_index(p, 'M', 2), 'M', -1)
              when p like '%T%S'
              then substring_index(substring_index(p, 'T', 2), 'T', -1)
              else ''
         end) +
        (case when p like 'T%M'
              then substring_index(substring_index(p, 'T', 2), 'T', -1) + 0
              else 0
         end) * 60
        ) as seconds
```

This does not generalize really easily as more time components are added.  The seconds component, for instance, is the second element when the splitter is 'M' or 'T'.  Sometimes, you just have to wonder what the ISO committee is thinking when they make these standards.

Note that MySQL converts a string to numbers using leading digits (if any).  The above uses this feature.

If you are supporting more complex period formats, then I would suggest writing a user-defined function and posting it here as an answer.

I will also note that SAS supports this format.  Better yet, they have really good [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003169814.htm) explaining it.

EDIT:

You can handle all formats more easily with this kludge.  It inserts a space after each component and then uses `substring_index()`:

```
select (case when newp like '%S'
             then substring_index(substring_index(newp, 'S', 1), ' ', -1) + 1
             else 0
        end) as seconds,
       (case when newp like '%M%'
             then substring_index(substring_index(newp, 'M', 1), ' ', -1) + 1
             else 0
        end) as minutes,
       . . .
from (select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(p, 'T', 'T '
                                                    ), 'Y', 'Y '
                                            ), 'D', 'D '
                                    ), 'H', 'H '
                            ), 'S', 'S '
                    ) as newp
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Hello, i edited my first post, and i attached the working PHP Code version of it. Can you please check it. thanks

Comment: It's very complicated and does not work with seconds. Because it has the miliseconds too. Can't we do it using regex like in PHP ?( first post)

Comment: @OhGodWhy . . . This should work fine for milliseconds.  MySQL will convert the value before the S to a number, even if there is a decimal point.  MySQL doesn't offer anything like replace with a regular expression.