# Convert ISO 8601 duration to decimal time SQL values such as PT7H30M or PT8H0M

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, duration, iso8601

I need to convert a field that has ISO 8601 duration in a `varchar` field to a decimal value representing that duration in hours.

How would I do a `SELECT` using the following data so results come back with the row values of 8.0 (`PT8H0M`), 7.5 (`PT7H30M`) and 1.0 (`PT1H0M`) for the duration field?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[timetracking](
    [qbsql_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [username_id] [int] NULL,
    [TxnDate] [datetime2](0) NULL,
    [Duration] [varchar](50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([qbsql_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[timetracking] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[timetracking] ([qbsql_id], [username_id], [TxnDate], [Duration]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(N'2018-02-02T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), N'PT8H0M')

INSERT [dbo].[timetracking] ([qbsql_id], [username_id], [TxnDate], [Duration]) VALUES (2, 2, CAST(N'2018-02-01T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), N'PT7H30M')

INSERT [dbo].[timetracking] ([qbsql_id], [username_id], [TxnDate], [Duration]) VALUES (3, 1, CAST(N'2018-02-01T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), N'PT1H0M')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[timetracking] OFF
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question and no evidence of research or any other effort, Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get ISO-8601(SCORM 2004) Duration Format in Seconds using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172258/get-iso-8601scorm-2004-duration-format-in-seconds-using-mysql)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Great job on posting sample data as DDL+DML. However, here we expect to see what you have already tried  before posting the question. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add your current attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Also, can you have longer durations in your table? days? months? years?

Comment: I know how to do that in Java. Do you need to do it in SQL?

Comment: You could try tossing together a [state machine to parse](https://medium.com/@brianray_7981/tutorial-write-a-finite-state-machine-to-parse-a-custom-language-in-pure-python-1c11ade9bd43) [ISO 8601 Duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) strings and let us know what _specific_ problems you encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in function I'm afraid.
I just wrote one, which is fully inlineable ad-hoc SQL - but it won't be fast...

You can try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertISO8601Periode2Seconds(@periode VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH Variables AS
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('T',@Periode)>0 THEN CHARINDEX('M',@periode,CHARINDEX('T',@Periode))-1 ELSE -1 END AS posMinute
          ,REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@periode,2,LEN(@periode)),'T','0') AS Original
)
,SwitchMinute AS
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN posMinute>0 THEN STUFF(Original,posMinute,1,'X') ELSE Original END AS WorkWith
    FROM Variables
)  
,recCTE AS
(      
    SELECT CAST(0 AS FLOAT) AS Seconds
          ,1 AS StartPos
          ,2 AS nextPos
          ,WorkWith 
    FROM SwitchMinute

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CASE SUBSTRING(r.WorkWith,r.nextPos,1) 
                WHEN 'Y' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(r.WorkWith,r.StartPos,r.nextPos-r.StartPos) AS FLOAT) * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
                WHEN 'M' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(r.WorkWith,r.StartPos,r.nextPos-r.StartPos) AS FLOAT) * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
                WHEN 'W' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(r.WorkWith,r.StartPos,r.nextPos-r.StartPos) AS FLOAT) * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60
                WHEN 'D' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(r.WorkWith,r.StartPos,r.nextPos-r.StartPos) AS FLOAT) * 24 * 60 * 60
                WHEN 'H' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(r.WorkWith,r.StartPos,r.nextPos-r.StartPos) AS FLOAT) * 60 * 60
                WHEN 'X' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(r.WorkWith,r.StartPos,r.nextPos-r.StartPos) AS FLOAT) * 60
                WHEN 'S' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(r.WorkWith,r.StartPos,r.nextPos-r.StartPos) AS FLOAT) * 1
           ELSE 0
           END + r.Seconds
           ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(r.WorkWith,r.nextPos,1) IN('Y','M','W','D','H','X','S') THEN r.nextPos+1 ELSE r.StartPos END 
           ,r.nextPos + 1
           ,r.WorkWith
    FROM recCTE AS r
    WHERE r.nextPos<=LEN(r.WorkWith)
)
SELECT @periode AS ISO8601Periode
      ,MAX(Seconds) AS Seconds 
FROM recCTE;
GO
```

--You call it like this

```
DECLARE @SomePeriodes TABLE(p VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @SomePeriodes VALUES('P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S'),('PT8H0M'),('PT7H30M'),('PT1H0M');

SELECT ISO2Sec.ISO8601Periode
      ,ISO2Sec.Seconds
      ,ISO2Sec.Seconds/(60*60) Hrs
FROM @SomePeriodes AS p
CROSS APPLY dbo.ConvertISO8601Periode2Seconds(p.p) AS ISO2Sec;
GO
```

--Clean up

```
DROP FUNCTION dbo.ConvertISO8601Periode2Seconds;
```

The result

```
ISO8601Periode      Seconds     Hrs
P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S    110550605   30708,5013888889
PT8H0M              28800       8
PT7H30M             27000       7,5
PT1H0M              3600        1
```

### Some explanation

Regretfully ISO 8601 periods can use the `M` for months as well as for minutes. If there is a `T` within the string, the `M` **after the `T`** is the minute. I replace this with `X` in order to work straight through the string.

The central code is a recursive CTE trailing down the string *char-by-char*, remembering the position of the last number's start and looking for non-numbers. Whenever one letter is found, the numeric value before is multiplied accordingly and added to the previous value - thus accumulating all values.

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates a Poor Man's Parser for a subset of the ISO 8601 Duration format.

- It handles only time fields: hours, minutes and seconds.
- It does not handle date fields: years, months, weeks and days. They could be added by extending the code in a straightforward manner.
- It supports decimal fractions, e.g. "PT12.5S".
- It does not verify that field values, particularly decimal fractions, are well formed, e.g. "0,2.3". (CAST may catch some errors, but the parser isn't looking for them.)
- It does not verify that only the smallest unit has a decimal fraction. (This could be implemented as a check in the final SELECT to ensure that a radix point, if any, only appears in the smallest non-empty unit.)
- It does not perform validation of general order, i.e. that fields must progress from larger to smaller units. (This could be implemented by adding a column to track "used" fields, e.g. as a bitmask.)

```
-- Sample input.
declare @Period as VarChar(128) = 'PT12H56.7S';

-- Parser.
with PeriodFields as (
  select Cast( '' as VarChar(128) ) as Hours, Cast( '' as VarChar(128) ) as Minutes, Cast( '' as VarChar(128) ) as Seconds,
    Cast( '' as VarChar(128) ) as Field,
    Substring( @Period, 2, 1 ) as Character, -- The next character to be processed.
    Substring( @Period, 2, 128 ) as Remainder -- The remainder of the input string.
    where LEFT( @Period, 2 ) = 'PT' -- Handle only periods (P) that consist only of a time (T) without years, months, weeks or days.
  union all
  select
    -- Save the accumulated field value when there is a field identifier, i.e. 'H', 'M' or 'S'.
    case when Character = 'H' then Field else Hours end,
    case when Character = 'M' then Field else Minutes end,
    case when Character = 'S' then Field else Seconds end,
    -- Accumulate characters in   Field   until there is a field identifier, i.e. 'H', 'M' or 'S'.
    Cast( case when Character like '[0-9.,]' then Field + Character else '' end as VarChar(128) ),
    Substring( Remainder, 2, 1 ), Substring( Remainder, 2, 128 )
    from PeriodFields
    where Remainder != '' )
  select *,
    -- Assemble the field values into an instance of   Time .
    Cast( DateAdd( millisecond, Cast( Seconds as Float ) * 1000.0,
      DateAdd( second, Cast( Hours as Float ) * 3600 + Cast( Minutes as Float ) * 60, 0 ) ) as Time ) as Period
    from PeriodFields
    where Remainder = ''; -- Comment out this line to see the intermediate results.
```

Comment: This is quite limited and can not deal with periodes exceeding 24 hours. I think, talking about duration, the target should be `DATETIMEOFFSET` or any appropriate numeric value representing a (small) unit. If one needs a date or time this can easily be achieved in a *follow-up* step.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the current answers, I would like to suggest a solution that is not based on a recursive CTE.

My solution does not validate the values at all, only tries to parse them.
I've only implemented parsing the time parts (hours, minutes and seconds), but it's very easy to extend to support other parts as well.

That being said, I'm not sure that this is the best thing to do with duration. Once you specify a number of months, You can't have a deterministic function to translate the ISO8601 duration into a number representing any time unit, since a month can have anywhere between 28 to 31 days.

The way I see it, such duration can only be used to calculate a DateTime value by adding or subtracting the duration from another DateTime value.

Now, enough talk, let's see some code!

Use a cte to get the positions of all the parts of the duration,
and another cte to handle missing values (i.e `PT30M`):

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  [qbsql_id], 
            [username_id], 
            [TxnDate], 
            [Duration],
            CHARINDEX('P', Duration) As Ppos,
            NULLIF(CHARINDEX('Y', Duration), 0) As Ypos,
            NULLIF(CHARINDEX('M', Duration), 0) As Monpos,
            NULLIF(CHARINDEX('D', Duration), 0) As Dpos,
            NULLIF(CHARINDEX('T', Duration), 0) As Tpos,
            NULLIF(CHARINDEX('H', Duration), 0) As Hpos,
            NULLIF(CHARINDEX('M', Duration, CHARINDEX('T', Duration)), 0) As Minpos,
            NULLIF(CHARINDEX('S', Duration), 0) As Spos
    FROM timetracking
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  [qbsql_id], 
            [username_id], 
            [TxnDate], 
            [Duration],
            Ppos,
            COALESCE(Ypos, Ppos) AS Ypos,
            COALESCE(Monpos, Ypos, Ppos) AS Monpos,
            COALESCE(Dpos, Monpos, Ypos, Ppos) AS Dpos,
            COALESCE(Tpos, Dpos, Monpos, Ypos, Ppos) AS Tpos,
            COALESCE(Hpos, Tpos, Dpos, Monpos, Ypos, Ppos) AS Hpos,
            COALESCE(Minpos, Hpos, Tpos, Dpos, Monpos, Ypos, Ppos) AS Minpos,
            COALESCE(Spos, Minpos, Hpos, Tpos, Dpos, Monpos, Ypos, Ppos) AS Spos
    FROM CTE1
)
```

Select from that cte, calculating the hours it represents as a float value:

```
SELECT  [qbsql_id], 
        [username_id], 
        [TxnDate], 
        [Duration],
        0.0 + 
        CASE WHEN Ppos = 1 AND Tpos > 0 THEN -- a period containing a time part
            CASE WHEN Hpos > Tpos THEN
                ISNULL(CAST(SUBSTRING([Duration], Tpos+1, Hpos - Tpos-1) as float), 0)
            ELSE 
                0
            END
            + 
            CASE WHEN Minpos > Hpos THEN
                ISNULL(CAST(SUBSTRING([Duration], Hpos+1, Minpos - Hpos-1) as float), 0) / 60.0
            ELSE 
                0
            END 
            +
            CASE WHEN Spos > Minpos THEN
                ISNULL(CAST(SUBSTRING([Duration], Minpos+1, Spos - Minpos-1) as float), 0) / 60.0 /  60.0
            ELSE 
                0
            END 
        END AS DurationInHours
FROM CTE1
```

result:

```
qbsql_id    username_id     TxnDate                 Duration    DurationInHours
1           1               02.02.2018 00:00:00     PT8H0M      8
2           2               01.02.2018 00:00:00     PT7H30M     7,5
3           1               01.02.2018 00:00:00     PT1H0M      1
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/PTCS16508)

Comment: I did not find any relyable information, but I think it is allowed to omit parts (such as `PT1H1S`). And I'm pretty sure, that something like `PT10M` is allowed. And it might be allowed to change the order (e.g. `PT1S1H1M`)... However, this approach is not enough tolerant in my eyes...

Comment: Ommiting parts is allowed according to wikipedia, I think the order can't be changed.

Comment: That's what I found too. Your approach would break on `PT1M` I assume...

Comment: Correct, Deleting, regrouping, might post another one.

Comment: @Shungo I've found a solution to the problem you pointed out (check out the live demo). Would love some feedback.